# event.target.checked property is not working for checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some input **checkbox** which is created inside **ng-repeat**

```
<li ng-repeat="item in tasks track by $index">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-init="setChecked(item.status)"
           ng-checked="changeStatus(item.id)"
           ng-model="item.status" value="{{item.id}}">
    <span ng-model="item.title" ng-keyup="completeEdit(item.id)"
          contenteditable="false" ng-dblclick="contentEdit()"
          class="done-{{item.status}}">{{ item.title }}
     </span> 
</li>
```

What I am trying to achieve is, based on a data item property the checkbox should show either checked or unchecked. For that I am using **ng-init** of the checkbox. Below is the function I am calling in **ng-init**

```
$scope.setChecked = function(status) {
    event.target.checked = status;            
};
```

But the problem is the above function is not making change to checkbox. The checkbox is always showing unchecked even if the **status** is **true**

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in the above code?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: The `ng-model` directive doesn't work with `<span>` elements. Don't use `ng-checked` together with `ng-model`. The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`.

Comment: Read [`<input type="checkbox"` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D).

Comment: @georgeawg thanks for the reply. Agreeing with your point that no need of `ng-init` in this context. May be I should use `ng-change` to call the changeStatus function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the checkbox checked or unchecked I should have used `ng-checked` and for update the status I used `ng-change`. This fixed the problem for me.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="changeStatus(item.id)"
       ng-checked="item.status" ng-model="item.status"
       value="{{item.id}}">
```

Comment: Note the `ng-checked` directive should not be used together with `ngModel`, as this can lead to unexpected behavior. Use `ng-model` for two-way binding, `ng-checked` for one-way binding. See [AngularJS ng-checked Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).